# jsquery delay() not working on a set of a elements selected from class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Why doesn't the delay nor the fadeIn work in the below code?

I've tried wrapping it with the `queue` function to no avail - and I know the `.middle-man` class selection and `.each` is working OK because `console.log(this)` returns the correct `a` elements - so why is there no delay and no fade in? I've tried each on their own too, I've tried initial opacity = 0, hidden ... with the result always being the same: instant execution of the script and instant display of the elements!

```js
$(".middle-man").each(function() {
  $(this).delay(1000).fadeIn(3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="middle-man" href="">
  <p>SOme Stuff</p>
</a>
<a class="middle-man" href="">
  <p>SOme Stuff</p>
</a>
<a class="middle-man" href="">
  <p>SOme Stuff</p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is already visible that is why Jquery will not fade in. Try adding a style to the class to hide the links.

```
.middle-man {
  display: none;
}
```

OR inline

```
<a class="middle-man" href="" style="display:none;">
  <p>SOme Stuff</p>
</a>
```